# Unable to get the accurate value of shell variable set inside a pipe

Tags: linux, shell

I am trying to set a variable, based on the execution result of a MySQL statement like this:

```
    errorOut=0
    mysql -uroot -pinsite3 -rN --execute "select file_system_id from ifm.PartitionTable where physical_partition='$partName'" | while read myVal
    do
      echo "myVal = $myVal"
      if [ $myVal -eq $fsId ];then
        errorOut=1
        echo "Found equal: errorOut = $errorOut"
      fi
    done
    echo "Outside loop: errOut = $errorOut"


Here is the output:
myVal = 1
myVal = 2
Found equal: errorOut = 1
Outside loop: errOut = 0
```

As you can see, due to pipe I am unable to get the value of the variable outside the loop (as the variable inside pipe, is basically set forking a different process)

Is there any way i can extract the actual value outside the loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What if you use a `for...in` instead of `read`, like this? :

```
errorOut=0
for myVal in $(mysql -uroot -pinsite3 -rN --execute "select file_system_id from ifm.PartitionTable where physical_partition='$partName'")
do
  echo "myVal = $myVal"
  if [ $myVal -eq $fsId ];then
    errorOut=1
    echo "Found equal: errorOut = $errorOut"
  fi
done
echo "Outside loop: errOut = $errorOut"
```

Answer (score 1):

Write it to a file, and then read the file outside the loop.

```
errorOut=0
errOutFile=Err$$.txt
mysql -uroot -pinsite3 -rN --execute "select file_system_id from ifm.PartitionTable where physical_partition='$partName'" | while read myVal
do
  echo "myVal = $myVal"
  if [ $myVal -eq $fsId ];then
    errorOut=1
    echo "Found equal: errorOut = $errorOut"
    echo "$errorOut" > $errOutFile
  fi
done
errorOut="$(cat $errOutFile)"
```

Comment: The code might be running on sensitive memory constraint devices, so want to avoid this approach if possible.

Comment: Ah... So do you mean you don't want to write files at all, or you don't want to write big files?

Comment: The other answer by Yannoff seems to fit your purpose.

Comment: Yes, and thanks for your answer too, upvoted, as it is also a solution